# How to retrieve C++ class info other then RTTI

Tags: c++, rtti

Here are three classes,

```
class ClassA{};
class ClassB:public ClassA{};
class ClassC:public ClassB{};

ClassC cobject;
```

I want to know the cobject's "Class Name"(i.e. ClassC) and its "SuperClasses' Name"(i.e. ClassB & ClassA)

I know RTTI can do this. But I'm wondering if I can do this with a few macros.

Comment: I think regardless you will have to use `typeid` or put some information in your class to do what you want.

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is no, you can't do that with a few macros if you don't want to use RTTI.

However, you can get a lot of useful information about class types using templates on your own or using a library like the [Boost.TypeTraits](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_41_0/libs/type_traits/doc/html/index.html). For example, you can test if a class inherits from another using `is_base_of()`